# Windows 10 causing reboot loop

Tags: windows-10

I upgraded to Windows 10 immediately after it came out and of course there were bsod's and hiccoughs. The out came the SP and that seemed to fix it all.

Recently, I have come into a weird issue where my computer will begin a reboot loop where it reboots in the middle of whatever I am doing and then continue to reboot from the subsequent windows loading screen or just after I log back into windows.

The consistent triggers (actions I am performing) are when I am accessing something via internet or watching video.

Further, there is nothing in the eventviewer, seemingly no memory dump, etc. All device drivers look to be working fine in the device manager. Driver Talent says only two drivers are out of date (md chipset and audio) and three classified as updatable but are ok. They were all working fine until weeks ago so I don't feel they are the culprits.

[image: Driver check results from Driver Talent]

I have recently installed FortiClient so that I may work remotely and it is only the vpn client as opposed to their full package. So there is no security software conflict.

I don't download a great deal of software, only when needed and all are ones that work fine elsewhere. Certainly nothing since the SP, except for forti.

It seems to happen more frequently when I do multiple things using like connected to forti vpn and watching a video, or using forti and firefox, etc. I know forti sounds like the common issue but it works on other machines, why fail here?

Anyway, I'd appreciate your ideas.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! It was the cpu fan that died! Because of the awkward angle in my case, it was not the obvious cause but the cpu self preservation from overheating explains everything. And the new fan worked...